# How to plot multiple points in Matlab in a GUI interface?

Tags: matlab

I need to create a GUI in Matlab which plots points (the user can however many points they want), then allows the user to draw a line using a least squares method.

I have 2 main problems.

1. My code doesn't create variables in the workspace, so I can't do anything with the data.
2. At the moment, my program just updates the one point I give.

Here is my current code:

```
function varargout = florin(varargin)
% FLORIN MATLAB code for florin.fig
%      FLORIN, by itself, creates a new FLORIN or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = FLORIN returns the handle to a new FLORIN or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      FLORIN('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in FLORIN.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      FLORIN('Property','Value',...) creates a new FLORIN or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before florin_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to florin_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help florin

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 16-May-2017 02:02:26

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @florin_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @florin_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before florin is made visible.
function florin_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to florin (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for florin
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes florin wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = florin_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;



function x_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of x as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of x as a double
valx=str2num(get(handles.x,'String'));
setappdata(0,'x',valx);

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function x_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function y_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to y (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of y as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of y as a double
valy=str2num(get(handles.y,'String'));
setappdata(0,'y',valy);
% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function y_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to y (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
m=getappdata(0,'x');
n=getappdata(0,'y');
plot(m,n,'r.','MarkerSize',20);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regards Florin. Based on the question, I can understand that you would like to create a GUI such that a user can input a set of points, then plot them, and also find and plot the best fit line using least square method. And in your progress you encounter 2 problems.

For the 1st problem. If you want to **send/create** to, and **take** a variable from the workspace, via the m-file, you could use `assignin` and `evalin` function.

```
assignin('base','x',100);
y=1+evalin('base','x');
```

The short code above creates a variable `x` in the workspace through the m-file, and then takes it for the variable `y`, which will become `y=101`. You can read more here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html.

Sorry, I don't understand your 2nd problem.

You could try this first. Thank you.

Comment: I would highly discourage using either of these functions as they can yield unexpected behavior.

Comment: Regards @Suever 
What kind of unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Well, what happens if the user already has a variable named `x` in the base workspace? Also, `eval` and it's relatives should be avoided at all costs. There are much more elegant ways to get data from a GUI. Specifically for GUIDE, you can create a function to return data as an output.

Comment: It will update the existing variable `x`. 

I don't quite understand your last line, you mean not through creating variables in workspace? 

The 1st problem is specific about creating a variable in workspace, and then use it.